# Should I add __init__.py to github?

Tags: python

I needed an empty `__init__.py` file in order to call a class from my main in a project I was working on. If I understand correctly, this is the constructor?

Since github doesn't allow files that are empty to be added to my repository, I was wondering if it actually wasn't necessary for my project or if I needed a work around?

Answer (score 6):

[`__init__.py`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) files are markers that mark a directory as a package (that can be imported from). If you *should* make a directory a package, then better commit it to github.

I'm not sure why you're saying that empty files cannot be committed, you can take stackstorm as an example:

https://github.com/StackStorm/st2/tree/master/st2api/st2api

and see that such files indeed gets committed.

Comment: Okay thank you for your answer. It turns out I can indeed create files, whereas I was trying to upload an empty file.

Answer (score 4):

Just write a comment in the `__init__.py`. that will do.

Comment: I found a different workaround - but it's helpful to know that works too!

Comment: Great, do let us know the workaround. it will be helpful for other's

Comment: you can share another workaround, will help @JamieAlizadeh